# How do I install camel-cxf feature for camel 3.8.0 in Apache Karaf 4.2.15?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, camel-cxf

This works:

```
karaf@root> feature:repo-add camel 3.7.7
karaf@root> feature:install camel camel-cxf
```

This doesn't work:

```
karaf@root> feature:repo-add camel 3.8.0
karaf@root> feature:install camel camel-cxf
```

Error message:

```
Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity;
osgi.identity=camel-cxf; type=karaf.feature; version="[3.8.0,3.8.0]";
filter:="(&(osgi.identity=camel-cxf)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=3.8.0)(version<=3.8.0))"
[caused by: Unable to resolve camel-cxf/3.8.0: missing requirement [camel-cxf/3.8.0]
osgi.identity; osgi.identity=cxf-core; type=karaf.feature; version="[3.3.0,4.0.0)"]
```

Why did this stop working between these two versions, or rather how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding apache cxf feature-repository and installing cxf feature first?

**Example:**

```sh
feature:repo-add cxf <version>
feature:install cxf

feature:repo-add camel 3.8.0
feature:install camel
feature:install camel-cxf
```

Camel feature-repository has entry for apache-cxf feature-repository with version range set to [3.0.0 - 4.0.0](https://github.com/apache/camel-karaf/blob/camel-karaf-3.8.0/platforms/karaf/features/src/main/resources/features.xml#L21) which might cause it to use [incompatible version](https://michakutz.medium.com/legit-but-useless-maven-version-ranges-explained-d4ba66ac654) of apache-cxf or its feature-repository.

The missing cxf-core feature should be available in cxf-feature repository and if you install cxf feature first camel-cxf should just use the pre-installed version instead of trying to install latest version which could very well be something like 4.0.0-alpha since it's technically lower than 4.0.0.